# How to install ubuntu on MSI GE63 without 'acpi=off'

Tags: system-installation, acpi, msi

I tried to install Ubuntu on MSI GE63 Raider 8RF 004cn. But I have to add line 'acpi=off' while installation, the fan spins very fast after I enter Ubuntu. I have searched a lot on the internet but no perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same [issue on the same laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues/1059435#1059435) . In short: update the bios. You can find the update files [here](https://www.msi.com/Laptop/support/GE63-Raider-RGB-8RF). Just remember to disable secure boot and fast boot again after updating the bios.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too on a ge63 raider 8re. Like palia5 said, the solution for me was updating the bios, then adding acpi=off for the installation of Linux Mint (hope it's the same for ubuntu) and afterwards changing acpi=off to acpi_osi=Linux, now everything works fine.