# Unable to boot or install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, acpi

I installed Ubuntu on a brand new MSI GS65 and everything worked great. After I connected my monitor using USB-C it asked to add it to the list of authorized devices which I did.

However a reboot later I started to see a slew of logs that look like:

`ACPI Error : No handler or method registered for GPE xx : Disabling event YY.`

I just see the spew of logs. Windows continues to boot great. I removed Ubuntu completely and formatted the HDD which contained the Ubuntu install to NTFS. The second HDD is working well and I got back to a setup where I only have Windows.

At this point I tried to reinstall Ubuntu from a USB and this time the installer won’t boot at all (with the same errors). This is the same USB I used to install Ubuntu to begin with.

Any ideas on what might be going on, and what I can do to fix this?

I have Secure Boot turned off.

Comment: I get several ACPI errors but my system works fine. Some brands/models need boot parameters. See: MSI GS65  Boot parameter: modprobe.blacklist=nouveau 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061109/dual-boot-windows-10-cannot-boot-latest-ubuntu-but-only-older-versions
MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`oldfred` is correct. I performed a UEFI BIOS update, and we are back in business. Thank you so much.

Additional Note: Enabling Thunderbolt Firmware Updates in the BIOS also causes things to break. So don't do that either.