# Dual boot 18.04 LTS with Windows 10 -> failed

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I tried to build a dual-boot system with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. The WSL option is not fit for my purpose (missing the option of installing a full GUI), therefore dual-boot seems the way to go. 
Followed the manual(s) but the moment I try to reboot the system from a USB drive it gives me two errors and then it stops booting completely.

The first error:

```
[    0.2885711] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating [\_SB.PCI0.RP05.PXSX.TBDU], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324)
```

Second error:

```
[    0.2885771] ECPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20181213/psobject-221)
```

Anyone an idea? I picked some ICT brains around here in- and outside the company and they even suggested that installing Ubuntu on this laptop (be it dual boot or as primary OS) would likely not be possible at all due to the fact that the system is too new...

Some laptop specs: 
MSI GT75 Titan 8SG, Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-8950HK CPU @ 2.90GHz, 2901 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s), RAM 32,0 GB.

Comment: You probably need boot parameters, older models did and offen issues are common. MSI GS65  Boot parameter: modprobe.blacklist=nouveau 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061109/dual-boot-windows-10-cannot-boot-latest-ubuntu-but-only-older-versions
MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off MSi GT72VR-6RE Dominator Pro - some settings required
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2365997

Comment: Did you check the vendor site for any BIOS/firmware updates?  Even new machines frequently need these updates.

Comment: @Harm Heusinkveld When you made the LiveUSB to boot from, did you follow these instructions? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 to verify the downloaded Ubuntu ISO, then https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0 to make the LiveUSB to install with? If not, please click [edit] above and tell us what guide you followed and what you did to make the USB. Please do not use Add Comment; instead, use [edit].