# Can`t get Ubuntu to work on external device

Tags: boot, nvidia, usb, ssd

I am trying to install Ubuntu for the 6th time now and cant get it to work. I want to install it on an extern PCIe SSD connected with my Laptop via Thunderbolt. So I started from Windows and used a Ubuntu 18.04 ISO to install it on an USB-Stick with Rufus. Than I boot from USB and start the Live-USB part and go through the installation process. Choosing the SSD as Bootloader. Everytime it got on of the following results.

1. It didnt work and it shut down everytime I boot from the SSD
2. The installation worked I could login but everytime I entered the settings or tryed to shut down the system everything froze and I had to kill the Laptop with the power button.
3. I see the Login screen but everytime after I log in the System shuts down.

I dont really know what is going on and cant find a proper step by step method on installing it on a extern device. Everytime it stops at a certain point and leaving me at a non functional state.... getting really frustrated by now.

Hope you can help me out here.

Greetings

Markus

System:

MSI GS65 8RE-079

GeForce GTX 1060

Intel Core i7 (8. Generation) 8750H

Comment: Not all machines will boot external drives, and some have strange quirks (eg. I've systems that will providing only one bootable device is inserted; it's menu cannot cope with multiple choices). Did you verify ISO after download? (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0) and then write to install media before install? (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck where CD is any media used, be it cd/dvd/hdd/ssd/thumb-drive/flash-card/..)  Why 18.04? Did you try the latest 18.04.4? or an earlier one?

Comment: Yeah did all this and yeah i used 18.04.4 the latest version. Sorry for missinfo ^^.

Comment: Is this an UEFI install? And are you adding an ESP to external drive? Posted work around to manually unmount & mount correct ESP during install #23 & #26
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
 You will need the nVidia proprietary drivers as part of the install. Many MSI systems need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. MSI GS65  Boot parameter: modprobe.blacklist=nouveau 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061109/dual-boot-windows-10-cannot-boot-latest-ubuntu-but-only-older-versions

Comment: To be honest... no idea what you are talking about.. :/ i am not familiar with BIOS, UEFI and so on. Thats the part where the step by step is lacking..^^

Comment: Connect External SSD onto your machine
    Connect Ubuntu installation medium onto your machine
    Enter BIOS, choose boot from Ubuntu installation medium
    In Ubuntu Installation type, choose Something else
    Find your external SSD on the list, look for drive other than /dev/sda. (Assuming you already had Ubuntu before)

    Once you found it—you can partition it, the basic Ubuntu installation contain:

        Root partition /

        Swap partition swap
    Click next --> continue.
    The rest steps is related to username, timezone etc.
Thats what i did so far.

Comment: I have been testing following method of installing Ubuntu to USB device for last three weeks, with success, It is working in BIOS and UEFI. It looks complicated but should only take ten minutes work from start to install. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step/1217839#1217839.

Comment: Thats a good step by step but I still doesnt understand every step.

Create a Live USB or DVD using SDC, UNetbootin, mkusb, dd, etc. (See Note 1 at bottom)

What does that mean? SDC? UNetbootin? mkusb? Is it enough like I did to create the Live-USB with the ISO and Rufus?

Its better than most explanations but still not easy to do if you are not familiar with the Vocabulary.