# Installing Ubuntu on a MSI GS65, freezes at login screen

Tags: system-installation, msi

Did anybody figure out how to successfully install Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04 on a MSI GS65 8RF? After finally installing it (after following [the steps in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdLe3Kao2Ok)), it freezes when I try to log in.

I've already disabled secure boot and set the BIOS to UEFI only.

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Edit: It is not a duplication, MSI GS65 still freezes even after BIOS update

Comment: Do you have RAID drives? If not RAID 0, change to AHCI. [SOLVED] MSI GT72S 6QE - Freezes on boot unless acpi=off is used
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2303544 & MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off

Comment: It is not a duplication, MSI GS65 still freezes even after BIOS update.
I have succeeded with installing Ubuntu 18.04 and my recipe is the following:

  1. Update BIOS

  2. When loading from Live Ubuntu stick, do add `nouveau.modeset=0` to kernel arguments at the initial screen (when `Try Ubuntu...` etc are shown)

  3. From the Live Ubuntu install the Ubuntu system on the HDD/SDD

  4. Right after loading system install `nvidia-driver-410`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I've solved it the same way. I'll post a detailed description on how to install ubuntu on the MSI GS65 later.

Comment: @Thommy257 Post is reopened. Please post your answer. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, add "nouveau.modeset=0" and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, that the installation freezes, has been fixed by the Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS version. It comes with the 4.18 kernel by default and lets you install Ubuntu without any problem. However, after installation, it still freezes after attempting to log in.
To fix this, you have to boot your the Linux kernel with the `nomodeset` option. Here's what you do:

1. Follow [this instruction](https://askubuntu.com/a/38834/858358) on how to boot your Linux kernel with the `nomodeset` option.
2. Log into your computer (It will be in 800x400 pixel mode)
3. Enter the terminal with `ctrl` + `T`
4. Install the latest Nvidia driver. It occurred to me, that it's easier to install the driver from the `graphics-drivers` repository than from Nvidia directly. To find out the latest driver version, go to the [Nvidia drivers page](https://www.geforce.com/drivers/) and type in your GPU information (GTX1070, Linux-64bit). Right now it is version `430`. Then run:

   - `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`
   - `sudo apt-get update`
   - `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-430`

(if the last step failed, try `sudo apt-get install nvidia-430`)

Now reboot your computer and you should be set. Validate the driver installation by running `nvidia-smi` in a terminal.