# Ubuntu got installed, but no GRUB screen?

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, ssd, windows-10, ahci

I managed to install Ubuntu onto a SSD on AHCI mode. Alongside Win 10. Win 10 was pre-installed, has a boot loader in the UEFI, and in the UEFI there is nothing named Linux to begin with.

How to get Ubuntu running?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? How you boot install media, UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. And if Windows is UEFI, you need to install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode.  May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Windows 10 ist pre installed so that might be why it doesn't boot. Win 10 has its windows boot manager in the UEFI. I really don't know how I installed Linux. First I created the CD. Then, I changed to AHCI. Then I went to the UEFI and changed to CD USB (where Linux install is) to the first to boot-order. Then I installed.

Comment: I have no idea how I get the boot-info summary...

Comment: See link above. You use Ubuntu live installer and add Boot-Repair, use second option. Then run the Summary Report which will be uploaded to a pastebin site. Then just post link to pastebin site here, not entire report.

Comment: Alright, also, I think Windows is pre-installed on RAID, Ubuntu on AHCI, because on RAID Ubuntu couldn't find any SSD's (NVM).

Comment: @oldfred OK, so here is the link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rntDSkqD2h/

Comment: If you go into your UEFI boot menu, do you not this this? `Boot0001* ubuntu; It will not have the Boot0002 as it is second in UEFI boot choice. What brand/model system? You could run the fix from Boot-Repair, but it looks like it should boot without that fix.

Comment: I repaired with the Boot-Repair tool, and it told me that it managed to fix the problem but that I need to change the boot order. This is what I can change in the UEFI. UEFI USB CD/DVD, UEFI USB Key, UEFI CD/DVD, UEFI Hard Disk: Windows Boot Manager, UEFI USB Hard Disk, UEFI USB Floppy and UEFI Network.

Comment: Also, it's a MSI Infinte A.

Comment: Windows boots without problem in both AHCI and RAID, but even after using the tool it still doesn't show GRUB.

Comment: Boot-Repair would have copied shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is the fallback or hard drive entry. That normally is just a copy of Windows boot entry. Does boot of UEFI: hard disk boot Ubuntu? When in UEFI and using Boot tab, does that show ubuntu as an option? MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off

Comment: I can not hard disk boot Ubuntu. And Ubuntu is also not showing in the UEFI Boot "tab", which is not a tab in itself but an animated row of icons. So what can I do now?

Comment: The boot tab is in the UEFI menu with all the other UEFI settings like Secure Boot, not the UEFI boot. Usually UEFI menu is f2 and boot menu f12 when booting with many brands, but it does vary by brand. Do you have UEFI Secure boot off? It may be called "Windows" or "Other" but fine print will say if installing Windows 7 use "Other" as Windows 7 does not support UEFI Secure boot.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I actually found Ubuntu listed in the boot tab. I changed it to boot before Windows, so GRUB2 appeared.