# Boot does not recognize USB

Tags: boot

It is a novice question, but take it easy on me. I try to boot my computer from USB, without success. I have already tried several operational systems (Xubuntu, Linux Mint, Ubuntu) but none has recognized the USB rather than Debian. I change the BIOS boot option to USB Hard Disk. My computer is a MSI GE60.

Best Regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (like Xubuntu) are on-topic here, so Linux Mint & debian are off-topic. My first thought is the how did you write your install media (it's likely flawed)  The guide https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0 contains links for how to create a bootable USB stick under windows, Ubuntu or macOS - but please limit yourself to Ubuntu/official flavors (like Xubuntu) here.

Comment: check boot options like UEFI/BIOS in your computer, sometimes an image works as one and not the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootable USB of Ubuntu Minimal CD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689258/bootable-usb-of-ubuntu-minimal-cd)

Comment: I already tried to set the UEFI BIOS as you mentioned.

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and if SSD, SSD firmware? MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off