# my msi computer won't dual boot with ubuntu and windows and go straight to windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have a msi laptop with windows pre-installed and wanted to dual-boot ubuntu 20.04. I installed ubuntu on a single ext4 partition. but it goes straight to Windows when I turn on my PC. I tried reinstalling ubuntu to find out if my installation was wrong, but it was the same, Windows works fine, but ubuntu is installed.

How can I get the grub menu to work?

Comment: What model MSI? Older model, may be similar? MSI GE63 Update UEFI then acpi=off not required
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1059029/18-04lts-msi-ge63-boot-issues & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1038637/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-msi-ge63-without-acpi-off

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1):

At rhe startup sequence, press either F1, F2 or F8 multiple times.
Reason is there is a small time window to open the BIOS boot options menu. You should now be able to see a listing of possible boot options, e.g. windows, Linux.
Now you can choose to boot to a different one.

If you want to change your default boot options (which currently is Windows) you can Do that by going into the BIOS Setup. This one can normally ve accessed via your GRUB interface or the Boot options table. Often it is only called setup.
There you search for the option boot order and change it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it does not start the boot menu to choose the operating system when pressing any of those keys, I can open the bios menu when pressing delete, I would like to know if you know any alternative to open Ubuntu

Comment: You could change the default boot order in the BIOS setup.